# How to fix crash log error?

Tags: iphone

```
Incident Identifier: F15B3210-1FA9-4759-93D0-8EEFE5CDD41D
CrashReporter Key:   8745e40d4f9d62eca4e589e2fc071a4e41e1c65e
Hardware Model:      iPad2,2
Process:         MeetingMaker [3680]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/74EE8CB7-6CB1-4A2E-AD0F-AE8AF165AFE0/MeetingMaker.app/MeetingMaker
Identifier:      MeetingMaker
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]
Date/Time:       2012-07-27 13:01:06.571 +0530
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.1.1 (9B206)
Report Version:  104
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x375d388f 0x3751a000 + 759951
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x31648259 0x3163f000 + 37465
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3751c9db 0x3751a000 + 10715
3   MeetingMaker                    0x00034da3 -[MeetingMakerDetailViewController 
configureView] (MeetingMakerDetailViewController.m:114)
4   MeetingMaker                    0x00034f65 -[MeetingMakerDetailViewController
 viewDidLoad] (MeetingMakerDetailViewController.m:160)
5   UIKit                           0x30740c8b 0x30704000 + 248971
6   UIKit                           0x3073f461 0x30704000 + 242785
7   UIKit                           0x30731e87 0x30704000 + 188039
8   UIKit                           0x307a27d5 0x30704000 + 649173
9   MeetingMaker                    0x000342e9 -[MeetingMakerAppDelegate 
application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] (MeetingMakerAppDelegate.m:53)
```

### MeetingMakerAppDelegate.m:53

```
//line 53 is: [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [self createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded];
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.ViewController = [[MeetingMakerDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MeetingMakerDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.ViewController; 
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible]; 

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried asking `MeetingMaker` nicely not to call `abort()`?

Comment: Sorry i cant get you. can you be more specific?

Comment: I have checked for memory leaks but no issues in it. I have checked for xib file names for case sensitive it is perfect. What else do i need to check to fix up this crash log?